# Selecting multiple variables into model starting with common name in R

Tags: r

As in SAS we can start multiple varibles using colon(:) option with start name. I wanted to do the same in R for modeling purpose.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is more of a stackoverflow question...

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to do this.  Here is one with a regular expression that doesn't do exactly what you want, but might do the trick:

```
x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = rnorm(100)
z = rnorm(100)
a = rnorm(100)
y = x1+x2+z
d = data.frame(x1,x2,z,y)

X = as.matrix(d[,grepl("x",colnames(d))])
head(X)
m = lm(y~X+a)
summary(m)
```

Comment: so its basically subsetting the original data frame, can we have a method like vector of names, in similar fashion? Also, what we specify in the data=option in model step?

Comment: @user49305 If you don't coerce `X` to matrix but instead leave it as a data.frame, you can do `lm(y ~ . + a, data = X)`.

Answer (score 0):

`as.formula(paste("y~", paste(names(mydata)[substr(names(mydata), 1, 1)=="x"], collapse="+"))) -> myformula`
gives a formula object `myformula` for a regression of `y` on all variables with names beginning with `x` in the data frame `mydata` that you can use in models, e.g. `lm(myformula, data=mydata)`. So you're not sub-setting the data frame, which can be a nuisance when it's big.